# Rails Validation Issue on Form Submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two rails models associated with each other: students and courses. Multiple students can take multiple courses, so I decided to use a has_many_through association... as you can see below.

I also added an index to make sure a student does not enroll for a course twice. However, whe I try to enroll it doesn't go through.

student_enrollments:

```
    belongs_to :students
    belongs_to :courses

    validates :matriculation_number, presence: :true
    validates :course_code, presence: :true
```

student_enrollment schema

```
 create_table "student_enrollments", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "course_code", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "matriculation_number"
    t.index ["course_code"], name: "index_student_enrollments_on_student_id_and_course_code", unique: true
  end
```

student_enrollments_controller:

```
class StudentEnrollmentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_student!

    def new
        @courses = Course.all
        @course = []
        i = 0
        while i < @courses.length
            @course.push(@courses[i].course_code)
            i += 1
        end
        @enrollment = StudentEnrollment.new
    end

    def create
        @enrollment = StudentEnrollment.new(enrollment_params)

        if @enrollment.save
            flash[:success] = "enrollment successful."
            redirect_to new_student_enrollment_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Enrollment failed."
            redirect_to new_student_enrollment_path
        end
    end

    private

        def enrollment_params
            params.require(:student_enrollment).permit(:course_code, :matriculation_number)
        end
end
```

student

```
    has_many :student_enrollments
    has_many :courses, through: :student_enrollments
```

course

```
    has_many :student_enrollments
    has_many :students, through: :student_enrollments
```

I also added an index to make sure a student does not enroll for a course twice. However, whe I try to enroll it doesn't go through. The output when I try to create the entry via the console: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Students must exist, Courses must exist)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Rails 5, `belongs_to` associations are required, unless passing in the `optional: true` flag.

You can either update your associations so you can create a StudentEnrollment without a Student or Course passed in, or you can pass in  `student_id` and `course_id` attributes when creating the new object.

To disable those validations you can just do:

```
belongs_to :student, optional: true
belongs_to :course, optional: true
```

Comment: But I already have Students and courses... and I can't have enrollment without either a student or course.

Comment: In your `enrollment_params` method, you are only allowing `:course_code` and `:matriculation_number` as attributes to be used from all the params. You might just be missing `:user_id` and `:course_id` in the `.permit` method.

Comment: My student model has unique matriculation numbers and id... I don't know if I can pass the id into enrollment as student_id, which is why I used matriculation number.

Comment: I adjusted the view file so a user can't explicitly submit with any field blank.